# Angular sum dynamic data from *ngFor loop to get total, subtotal and vat value (%16)

Tags: angular

so I'm having a problem. I need to calculate total of tag.price on the fly from dynamic data in the *ngFor loop, also sub total and vat. Below is my html and also my ts code. The sub total, total and vat value will be outside of the loop just under this block. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let tag of locations">

 <td align="center"><span style="font-size: 17px;" class="menu-icon 
 icon-file-text2"></span></td>

 <td>{{tag.title}}</td>

 <th>{{tag.listingType}}</th>

 <th>{{ tag.size }}</th>

 <td>KSH {{tag.price | amount:locale}}</td>

 <td>KSH {{tag.price | amount:locale}}</td>

 </tr>


 // component ts
 setTags(id:any, title:any, price:any, listingType:any, size:any){
this.locations.push({
  title: title,
  id: id,
  price: price,
  listingType: listingType,
  size: size
});
```

}

Comment: I suppose you could use `#tag` then using `ViewChildren` make a forEach loop to get the values and count them.

Comment: what to you mean by total you mean sum of all tag price total inside an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use a function in the typescript<strike>, or you can just bind do an expression.</strike>

Function:

```
<div>
  {{ locationsSum() }}
</div>

public locationsSum() {
  return this.locations.map(tag => tag.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

<strike>Expression:</strike>

```
<div>
  {{ locations.map(tag => tag.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) }}
</div>
```

---

I'm not sure what you mean by "sub total" and "vat value", but assuming those are calculations based on the price, the concept should be the same.

---

EDIT: The Expression option I originally posted does not work. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14129 for more info.